# EntityFrameworkCore.Jet: Scaffold doest not work - COMException (0x800A0CB3)

Tags: ms-access, entity-framework-core, jet, scaffold, jet-ef-provider

**The problem**

When i try to scaffold the nordhwind.accdb i get a COM Exception

In VSCode Powershell Terminal:

```ps
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=<PATH>\northwind.accdb" EntityFrameworkCore.Jet -o Models
```

In Visual Studio 2022 Paket Manager Console:

```ps
Scaffold-DbContext -Connection "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=<PATH>\northwind.accdb" -Provider EntityFrameworkCore.Jet
```

The exception:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A0CB3): Das Objekt oder der Provider kann den angeforderten Vorgang nicht ausführen.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeDispMethod(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Object target, Object[] args, Boolean[] byrefModifiers, Int32 culture, String[] namedParameters)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)    
   at EntityFrameworkCore.Jet.Data.ComObject.TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, Object& result)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure, CallSite, Object)
   at EntityFrameworkCore.Jet.Data.AdoxSchema.GetColumns()
   at EntityFrameworkCore.Jet.Data.PreciseSchema.GetColumns()
   at EntityFrameworkCore.Jet.Data.JetStoreSchemaDefinition.JetInformationSchema.GetColumns(JetConnection connection)
   at EntityFrameworkCore.Jet.Data.JetStoreSchemaDefinition.JetInformationSchema.GetDbDataReaderFromSimpleStatement(JetCommand command)
   at EntityFrameworkCore.Jet.Data.JetStoreSchemaDefinition.JetInformationSchema.TryGetDataReaderFromInformationSchemaCommand(JetCommand command, DbDataReader& dataReader)
   at EntityFrameworkCore.Jet.Data.JetCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderCore(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at EntityFrameworkCore.Jet.Data.JetCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at EntityFrameworkCore.Jet.Scaffolding.Internal.JetDatabaseModelFactory.GetColumns(DbConnection connection, IReadOnlyList`1 tables)
   at EntityFrameworkCore.Jet.Scaffolding.Internal.JetDatabaseModelFactory.GetTables(DbConnection connection, Func`3 filter)
oryOptions options)
   at EntityFrameworkCore.Jet.Scaffolding.Internal.JetDatabaseModelFactory.Create(String connectionString, DatabaseModelFactoryOptions options)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.ReverseEngineerScaffolder.ScaffoldModel(String connectionString, DatabaseModelFactoryOptions databaseOptions, ModelReverseEngineerOptions__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
```

**What i have done so far**

I'm currently testing to connect to an existing access mdb using the EntityFrameworkCore.Jet provider. For test purposes i downloaded the latest northwind.accdb from here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/downloading-sample-databases

I opened the DB in Access and in Visual Studio 2022 (Server Explorer) to ensure it is accessible. Then i created a simple project with a `DbContext`:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="EntityFrameworkCore.Jet" Version="7.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="EntityFrameworkCore.Jet.Data" Version="7.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="EntityFrameworkCore.Jet.Odbc" Version="7.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="EntityFrameworkCore.Jet.OleDb" Version="7.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.15" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.15">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.OleDb" Version="7.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

```cs
public class JetTestContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseJet(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=<PATH>\northwind.accdb;");
        }
    }
```

I also made a little unit test to ensure a can instantiate the `JetTestContext`

But this should not influence the scaffolding in any way. I already searched but the only solutions i found are missing or wrong OLEDB drivers and i don't think thats my problem here as i can access the northwinddb, have Access installed and can browse the DB with the VS Server Explorer. What am i missing here?

**EDIT**
The Access Database Engine 2016 is also installed and the Unit Test is successful:

```cs
public void JetConnection()
{
    using (JetTestContext context = new JetTestContext())
    {
        context.Database.OpenConnection();
        context.Database.CloseConnection();
        Assert.IsTrue(context.Database.CanConnect());
    }
}
```

Comment: With Access installed drivers is important! Installed Access has no influence on that.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv

I installed the Access Database Engine 2016 - no change. And i don't think thats the reason because my connection test:

`using (JetTestContext context = new JetTestContext())
{
    context.Database.OpenConnection();
    context.Database.CloseConnection();
    Assert.IsTrue(context.Database.CanConnect());
}
`

is successful.

Comment: There could be 32/64 bit issue because the OleDb provider can be installed only in one version. Try also to post the issue on github